# tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: tensorflow

I was instaling tensorflow on my cpu when I got these 2 errors:

```
2022-03-13 17:59:56.171741: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2022-03-13 17:59:56.171872: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Can anybody help me out here a little bit because I was also following a tutorial from a few years ago.

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia GPU? If not, you can ignore the message. Else you need to be specific on what you want help with.

Comment: i cant ignore it and i have a Nvidia gpu 1030

Comment: Then you need to install appropriate cuda and cudnn versions, this is a common problem that has been extensively discussed in this site.

Comment: but i dont have a cuda enabled gpu i got that eror on my cpu version of tensor

Comment: You said you have a Nvidia 1030 which should support CUDA, and these messages are warnings, not errors (see the W in there?).

Comment: i know but when i wrote code in it it displayed a bunch of warnings i coud have screwd up the installsion proces but im preaty sure i did not. Im gona try whit my gpu and if dose not works im gona try agen from my cpu.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a `W`arning and `I`nformation message that CUDA libraries cannot be found.

The `I` message at line 2: `ignore the W message that comes above it if no CUDA GPU is installed on your machine.`

The only effect of this is that training will happen on CPU only.

If you are using NVIDIA GPU, you can refer to how to install the missing files.

If you don't use NVIDIA GPU, or simply want to ignore the `I` and `W` messages, you can add the 2 lines below at the beginning of your code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

> You can see more about `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` at [TensorFlow logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRMwZ.png).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cudart64 is the CUDA runtime dll. You need to download CUDA from [https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads](https://developer%20.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads:)

After installation the dll should be located under
c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v_11.0\bin
and this path should be on your PATH environment variable.

Don't forget to re-launch the terminal in which you are running python for the environment variables to update and become available for the terminal and python.